# modifing the function to capitalize every word of the given string and return the results

Tags: return

I think I get how to capitalize the string ('how do you do')by possibly using the caps method or title method. but how would I return it ? im confused by that.

would I do return('How Do You Do')[0].lower('How Do You Do') ?

im new to learning the stuff I watched didn't really help explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Python. You just have to use `.lower()` to the string.

```
print('How Do You Do'.lower())
```

Result:

```
how do you do
```

Alternately, you can make them all caps using `.upper()`

```
text = "How Do You Do"
text.upper()
```

Result:

```
HOW DO YOU DO
```

And capitalize only the first letter of each word using `.title()`

```
text.title()
```

Result

```
How Do You Do
```

**EDIT**

```
def convert_to_title(text):
    return text.title()

print(convert_to_title('how do you do?'))
```

Result:

```
How Do You Do?
```

Comment: how would I do the return ? and if the text.title() doesn't work then what should I try

Comment: @johnmanzella you want to pass the text to a function and return back the .title() output? See EDIT, if it hepls